# Cannot create example questions on Area51

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, example-questions

I can't create example questions on Area51. I have reputation 151, which should be enough according to the FAQ.

Actually I cannot do anything. When trying to upvote a comment I get a message "This comment is not eligible for voting or flagging". I cannot vote on example questions, I cannot do any of the things which my reputation would allow me to do.

The FAQ states that "You'll earn your first 50 reputation from confirming your email address. This will allow you to create proposals and example questions." and also contain a list with other levels:

- 25    Create example questions
- 50    Create proposals
- 50    Vote on example questions
- 50    Flag offensive
- 50    Leave comments
- 250   Vote to close or reopen your proposals
- 1000  Edit other people's posts (proposals and questions)
- 2000  Vote to close or reopen any proposal
- 10000     Delete questions and closed proposals, access to moderation tools

Comment: Which proposal?

Comment: Japanese: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese but I haven't tested anything else on any other proposal though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Japanese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese) proposal is in commitment phase. This means it no longer accepts votes or example questions, but is waiting for enough users to commit to launch in Beta.

Comment: Is must have been the phrase "Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site" in the FAQ which lead me to think otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Proposals in the Committment phase (like [Japanese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese)) cannot have new sample questions submitted, nor can their questions be voted on. Try a proposal in the Definition stage.